# SSH using Active directory credentials

Tags: bash, authentication, ssh, active-directory, rhel

I am using AWS, I can ssh using .pem file, I have also enabled password login by modifying /etc/sshd/sshd_config. I can create a new user and login with that user using password.

However, Instead of creating new user every time. I would like users to get authenticated from Active directory. I have a windows 2012 R2 instance running on AWS where I have configured users in Active directory;

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [sf] or [su].

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SSSD** to integrate your RHEL server with Active Directory.

For details on installing and configuring the SSSD service check the Red Hat documentation here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/SSSD-AD.html